# Como fazer ao fim de um tempo a cor de uma div mudar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom, a minha pergunta é a seguinte.

Como fazer um temporizador em um site, com contagem de decrescente de 30 segundos (Em tempo real), e quando chegar ao 0, a cor de uma div muda, mesmo que ninguém esteja no site isso tem que acontecer.

Como posso fazer?

Obrigado.

Comment: Ou seja, só mudar de cor para quem abrir a página depois de 30 segundos de uma certa hora?

Comment: Por exemplo, o temporizador conta 30 segundos, ou seja está a contar mesmo que não esteja ninguem no site, passado esses 30 segundos muda a cor de uma div, e o tempo volta de novo a 30, passado esses 30 volta a mudar de novo etc...

Comment: Qual é a linguagem que tens no servidor? quantas cores existem (e quais)? e como é gerado o código dessa div?

Comment: na verdade pode ser assim, em vez de mudar uma cor ao fim de 30 segundos ativar uma função no javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é útil pra você, mas dependendo do caso pode fazer com CSS utilizando key-frames.

> Demo: [https://jsfiddle.net/94pgnr6v/](https://jsfiddle.net/94pgnr6v/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="sua-div-aqui">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sua-div-aqui{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  // AQUI VOCÊ CHAMA A ANIMAÇÃO
  animation:         nome-animacao 150s steps(1) infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

`nome-animacao` é o nome do key-frame, `150s` é a duração total, `steps(1)` é para bloquear o efeito do [cubic-bezier](http://cubic-bezier.com/) e `infinite` para ficar repetindo a animação quando ela terminar.

As cores você iria definir dentro do key-frame:

```
@keyframes nome-animacao {
  0%  {background-color: #A100C7;}
  20% {background-color: #00A1E6;}
  40% {background-color: #A1E633;}
  60% {background-color: #E6B02E;}
  80%{background-color: #DC0063;}
}
```

> Perceba que definimos 150s anteriormente, dividindo por 5 cores é
> igual a 30 segundos cada cor.

Sempre que você quiser adicionar uma cor ou remover, deverá refazer esses cálculos.
No fim das contas, claro que é mais fácil fazer isso com Javascript.
Só quis mostrar outra forma de fazer isso sem usar programação.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var adicionaClasse = function(){
      $("#ControleID").addClass("ClasseAqui");
    };

    setTimeout(adicionaClasse, 2000);
});
```

OU

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#ControleID").addClass("ClasseAqui");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: O que é o controleid?

Comment: é o ID do controle que você quer adicionar a classe. ex. <input type="text" **id="abc"** value="" >